# Is smtplib pure python or implemented in C?

Tags: python, c, smtplib

Is smtplib pure python or implemented in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

smtplib itself is implemented in python but socket is based on C, so its means both.

Answer (score 8):

```
In [32]: import smtplib

In [33]: smtplib
Out[33]: <module 'smtplib' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.pyc'>
```

Therefore, smtplib is written in python.

Comment: +1
Hi ~unutbu! That's a neat way to investigate :D Thanks for the trick!

Comment: Not to be picky, but this wouldn't detect if smtplib is using a helper module (as part of the library) that is a native.

Comment: @notnoop: That's true, but since every Python implementation (other than PyPy) is written in another language, every module depends on something which is non-Python if you dig deep enough. Therefore I interpreted the question to mean, "Is the module itself written in Python?"

Comment: Well, there are a few modules whose Python module part is but a slim wrapper with a extra functions over the main implementation part from a _module C implementation.

Comment: notnoop generally I would count anything that's part of the standard library or only depending on c libraries in the std lib as pure python. So that assuming no implementation specific python apis used it would be portable among python implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Basically pure Python (as the underlying implementation if you go down far enough is C).  You can find the source under the Lib\ directory in your Python root.

Comment: thanks Wayne! I gave both answers +1 and thank you very much for participation. Since Mark arrived first, I give him the green mark. Thank you very much!